# Is it possible to overwrite default dialog options in @Component.providers?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I wanted to create a shared dialog with no backdrop (by default). I have overwritten MatDialogConfig injection token in this dialog's @Component decorator, like this:

```js
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { hasBackdrop: false } }]
})
class DialogComponent { }
```

However, it is not working: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialog-default-options?file=src/app/dialog/dialog.component.ts). I didn't want to do it in the module declaration, because it would be applied to all dialogs in this module, which is not what I want.

I also don't want to write `{ hasBackdrop: false }` every time I use it.

Is it possible to do so for this dialog only or do I have to specify this injection token modulewise?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the default options only for some of the dialogs across different components I would suggest to declare a constant as

```
export const DEFAULT_DIALOG_OPTIONS = { hasBackdrop: false };
```

And then whenever you are calling the open method you can override the options passed to it by using spread operator.

```
this._dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { ...dialogOptions, ...DEFAULT_DIALOG_OPTIONS });
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you do not need to specify the dialog options every time and still want a global option to be passed everytime MyDialogComponent is opened, I would suggest you create an injectable service

```
@Injectabl()
class MyDialogServic {
  constructor(dialog: MatDialog) {}

  methodToOpenDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { hasBackDrop: false })
  }
}
```

Now you can inject this service into any component and call its `methodToOpenDialog` in any other component where this service might be injected.

Comment: It is equivalent to writing `{ hasBackdrop: false }` every time I use this dialog. I don't want to specify dialog options.